# How does Firefox's inspect element determine the query selector of HTML elements?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to make a utility that lets me run JavaScript on an element through one of its attributes using `eval` and whatnot. I want to make it so that I can reference the element that is calling the JavaScript code with a variable called `thisEl`.

While I've been able to make a basic query selector generator, its a rather inefficient way of going about it.

So that lead me to wonder, what does Firefox use in inspect element (Ctrl+Shift+I, right click on any element -> copy -> CSS Selector)? I know its likely C++ or some other native language, but its likely translatable to JavaScript, no?

Edit: Here is some example code.

In HTML, I would have the following:

```
<div code="console.log(thisEl.tagName); // --> DIV."></div>
```

Ideally, I want the code to be executed by doing:

```
eval(`let thisEl = document.querySelector('${(QUERY SELECTOR HERE)}'); 
${(ELEMENTS CODE HERE)};`);
```

Comment: The page's markup determines the selector(s) that can be used to select the element, the browser only parses it. If you want a reference to an element, reference `this` inside a handler on the element? Maybe post your code, it's not entirely clear what you're looking for to me

Comment: @CertainPerformance I've added a code example, hopefully this explains what im trying to do.

Comment: What exactly is your use case? The internals of the browser application  are probably not going to help you

Comment: In particular, I’m trying to make a collection of tools that many frameworks have without having to use a big framework. In this case, I’m trying to run JavaScript code from an elements attributes. I thought it might be useful to look at Firefoxs source code as an example of how to go about it. @charlietfl

Comment: Collection of tools to do what exactly? Browser source code is not going to help you. Traversing the DOM with javascript itself is fairly straightforward but it's not at all clear what you are needing

Comment: When do you want to run the code on an element? Eg, do you want it to run automatically on pageload, or when a button (corresponding to the element) is clicked, or when a button corresponding to all elements is clicked, or when that element is clicked, or something like that?

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of that yeah. However, it’s not like the standard onload or onclick event listeners, rather it would be fired by using getAttributte paired with eval in JavaScript.

Comment: So you want to check all the elements in the dom, looking for a specific attribute, and then execute the JS in that attribute, and pass the query selector by string replacing your special `${(QUERY SELECTOR HERE)}` code with the selector string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know when you want to run the code of a particular element, select the element and then run its `code` as a `new Function`, defining a `thisEl` argument that you pass in:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const div = document.querySelector('div');
  const code = div.getAttribute('code');
  const fn = new Function('thisEl', code);
  fn(div);
});
```

```html
<div code="console.log(thisEl.tagName); // --> DIV."></div>
<button>click</button>
```

If you want to run the code of *all* elements with `code` attributes, use the `[code]` selector:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const elms = document.querySelectorAll('[code]');
  for (const elm of elms) {
    const code = elm.getAttribute('code');
    const fn = new Function('thisEl', code);
    fn(elm);
  }
});
```

```html
<div code="console.log(thisEl.tagName);"></div>
<div code="console.log('foo bar');"></div>
<button>click</button>
```

Using `new Function` is rarely a good idea, but since you want to retrieve the code text inside the attribute of an element and parse it into runnable Javascript, there's not really any other option.